# Pesquisar somente arquivos que casem parte do nome em um diretório

Tags: delphi

Tenho o seguinte problema

Em um determinado diretório vou precisar criar arquivos que obedeçam o seguinte critério.

DOCUMENTO_DDMM_SEQ.txt

Onde

- **Documento** : Um número qualquer que pode ou não se repetir
- **DDMM** : Dia + Mes da data corrente
- **SEQ** : Sequencial Global do diretório iniciando em 001

Para que eu consiga gerar o sequencial correto preciso saber o valor do último sequencial (maior valor)

Já consegui me aproximar lendo todos os arquivos do diretório para uma lista e iterando a lista em busca do ultimo valor, porém esse método é muito ruim, pois o diretório é de escolha do usuário e ele pode usar um diretório que contenha muitos arquivos, tornando essa pesquisa muito lenta.
Queria algo que já filtrasse os arquivos antes de eu ter que iterar a lista.

Qualquer sugestão será avaliada

Comment: 1º - Como o usuário vai escolher o diretório ? Vou começar a trabalhar em uma resposta!

Comment: Estou usando o método SelectDirectory da Unit FileCtrl depois uso a classe File para recuperar a lista de arquivos, itero esta lista analisando os nomes dos arquivos. 
Estou testando um código usando TSearchRec. Acho que é o caminho.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consegui fazer o que queria utilizando TSearchRec da seguinte forma.

```
procedure TFrm....
  var search : TSearchRec; // Unit SysUtils
    filename, dirname : String;
    seq, i : Integer;
Begin
  // (...)
  if not SelectDirectory('Selecione o diretório', 'arqs', dirname) then // Unit FileCtrl
    begin
       Application.MessageBox('Sem destino', APPNAME, MB_OK+MB_ICONERROR);
       Exit;
    end;
  try 
    // Pesquisando o diretório corrente para gerar arquivos únicos
    if (FindFirst(dirname + '*_' + FormatDateTime('ddmm', Date) + '_*.txt',
                    faArchive,
                    searchResult) = 0 ) then
      begin
        repeat
          // Extraindo o sequencial do arquivo
          i := LastDelimiter('_', searchResult.Name);
          if (TryStrToInt(copy(searchResult.Name, i, 3), i)) then
            seq := Max(i, seq);
        until FindNext(searchResult) <> 0;
        FindClose(searchResult);
      end;

    filename := NUMERO_DOCUMENTO + '_' +
                FormatDateTime('ddmm', Date) + '_' +
                LPad(IntToStr(seq + 1), 3, '0') + '.txt'; // LPad função privada de padding à esquerda
    // Garantindo que não existe arquivo com a nomenclatura passada
    while FileExists(dirname + filename) do
      begin
        seq := seq + 1;
        filename := NUMERO_DOCUMENTO  + '_' +
                    FormatDateTime('ddmm', Date) + '_' +
                    LPad(IntToStr(seq + 1), 3, '0') + '.txt';

      end;  

    // (Outros códigos ...)
End;
End.
```

Uma coisa que me ajudou neste código foi o uso de `TryStrToInt`, pois ele me permitiu evitar que um nome não finalizado em _999.txt fizesse a aplicação gerar uma `Exception` de conversão.

Aparentemente eu poderia ter problemas quando o sequencial chegasse em 999 pois o proximo a ser gerado seria o _1000.txt e ao invés de conseguir buscar o valor 1000, como estou limitando a 3 caracteres vai acabar pegando 100 e iterando na verificação de existência até o 1001. Vai acabar dando certo pelo jeito errado.

Uma solução seria buscar a posição de ".txt" para efetuar o calculo da quantidade de caracteres a ser utilizada tanto para a função `copy` quanto para o `padding`.